# Random Serial Dictatorship algorithm vs linear programming in solving an assignment problem

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, linear-programming

I just came across [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769336/low-computation-algorithm-for-near-optimally-assigning-n-options-to-n-users-give), which left me quite baffled.

If I had to assign N objects to N users, knowing that each user has expressed a rank preference for the objects, *with the goal to achieve the lowest possible average rank* (that is what the post states), my automatic choice would be linear programming.
Instead, this Random Serial Dictatorship is suggested, and it is stated that it achieves some form of optimality.

I was not sure how what looked to me like a greedy stochastic algorithm could *guarantee* optimality, so I tried it out.

Suppose that 3 users A, B, C have expressed rank preferences for 3 houses H1, H2, H3:

```
     user
house A B C
   H1 3 2 1
   H2 1 1 2
   H3 2 3 3
```

We want to assign a house to each user, so that the average (or sum) of ranks is minimal.

If I understood it correctly, the Random Serial Dictatorship algorithm requires choosing a random order for the users, and allow each of them to select the house they prefer.

For me it's clear that this kind of strategy may: 1) not result in the same sum of ranks each time, 2) consequently not guarantee optimality.

Imagine that A chooses first, B second and C third. A will select H2 (rank 1). But that's also B's preferred house, so B will have to go for H1 (rank 2), and C will be left with their least preferred house H3 (rank 3). Ranks = 1, 2, 3. Sum = 6, average = 2.
If, on the other hand, B chooses first, A second and C third: B = H2 (1), A = H3 (2), C = H1 (1). Ranks = 1, 2, 1. Sum = 4, average = 4/3.

As an R simulation:

```
# 3 users A, B, C want to buy a house each, chosen from H1, H2, H3.
# Their preferences are expressed by 'rank' (1 = first choice, 2 = second choice, etc).
d0 <- data.frame("user" = rep(c("A","B","C"), each = 3),
                "house" = rep(c("H1", "H2", "H3"), 3),
                "rank" = c(3,1,2,2,1,3,1,2,3)
                )

# 1. Assignment by random serial dictatorship

set.seed(232425)

all_ranks <- numeric(0)

for (i in 1:1000) {
  d <- d0
  # Create a random order of priority for the users.
  o <- setNames(sample(1:3), c("A","B","C"))
  # Let users choose their preferred house in turn, according to the created order.
  d["order"] <- o[d$user]
  d <- d[order(d$order, d$rank),]
  for (i in 1:2) {
    h <- d[i, "house"]
    d <- rbind(d[1:i,], d[(d$order > i) & (d$house != h),])
  }
  ranks <- d$rank
  ranks <- ranks[order(d$user)]
  all_ranks <- rbind(all_ranks, ranks)
  #print(d)
}

all_ranks <- setNames(as.data.frame(all_ranks), c("A","B","C"))
all_ranks_summary <- cbind("ID" = 1, setNames(stack(all_ranks), c("rank", "user")))
all_ranks_summary <- aggregate(ID ~ user + rank, all_ranks_summary, length)

barplot(ID ~ rank + user, all_ranks_summary, beside = TRUE, col = 2:4, legend.text = TRUE)
boxplot(rowMeans(all_ranks), main = "average rank")
```

Frequency of each rank for the 3 users and the average rank:

[image]
[image]

Clearly the average rank is not minimal in all cases.

Using a linear programming assignment method instead:

```
# 2. Assignment by linear programming

require(lpSolve)
cm <- xtabs(rank ~ house + user, d0)
lp.out <- lp.assign(cm)
lp.out$solution * cm
```

yields a guaranteed optimal solution:

```
     user
house A B C
   H1 0 0 1
   H2 0 1 0
   H3 2 0 0
```

My questions are:

**1. Am I misunderstanding the Random Serial Dictatorship algorithm? Can it actually be written in a way that guarantees optimality?

2. Is a linear programming assignment method almost as bad, computationally, as the brute force enumeration of all combinatorial possibilities?**

Perhaps I am wrong, but I'm just puzzled that one should start from a goal like:

> "assign each user an option so that the average rank of the assigned option in that user's ranked list is minimized across all users"

and then settle for an algorithm that, as 'fair' and as 'fast' as it may be, does not seem to achieve that goal at all.
Unless I am completely missing the point, which is possible.

Comment: Interesting mind teaser...  The other post only claims that using the serial picking approach leads to *pareto optimality*.  It isn't very clearly stated in the post, but it clearly does not lead to optimality as judged by the objective of minimizing average rank, as you have clearly shown with a toy 3x3 counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

It's "Pareto optimal", which is to say, not optimal in general. Pareto optimal just means that you would need to harm one or more of the participants to improve the objective.

Comment: Thanks, I had never thought about Pareto that way, it's interesting. The proof is shown in a [post](https://jeremykun.com/2015/10/26/serial-dictatorships-and-house-allocation/) that is linked in the post I mentioned. My problem was that the latter seemed to aim for absolute optimality but then settled for a different type of optimality. I still do not understand why LP is not even considered by the OP. I use it for many problems that would be combinatorially unfeasible, and I cannot complain about the results.

Comment: @user6376297 I use mathematical optimization libraries all the time, even for problems that are NP-hard, on instances that are way larger than the strong exponential-time hypothesis says I should be able to do successfully, so I don't know.